# offsetHeight wrong value provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to get a div height. My code is as below :

```
<div ng-repeat="col in columns">
  <div class="panel-default">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

My Angular code is :

```
//get elements
for(var i=0; i < columns.length ; i++)
console.log(angular.element(".panel-default")[i].offsetHeight);
```

The output in the console is incrementing something like :

```
111
180
223
265
...
2405
```

The height is wrong for elements, and it is not incrementing on UI as console shows. but when i display **angular.element(".panel-default")** and click to see for each element the offsetHeight parameter is correct.

I tried also with jQuery

```
$(.class).height()
```

and native javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].offsetHeight
```

But same result.
Why is that confusing ?

**Edit**

[image: Output for console.log($(".panel-default"))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing $timeout service.

```
$timeout(function(){
    for(var i=0; i < columns.length ; i++)
    console.log($(".class")[i].height());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the selector in JQuery, for classes and id's, you must use speech marks.
E.g:

```
$(".class").height();
```

So instead of Angular, try something like this:

```
//get elements
for(var i=0; i < columns.length ; i++)
    console.log($(".class")[i].height());
```

Comment: $(".class").height(); it is actually the same result (the wrong one) i tried it.
When using what you suggested, i have an exception (height is not a function)

Comment: In the for loop that you've provided, instead of logging the height, try to just log `console.log($(".panel-default"));`. What does that provide? I assume this provides an array on each log?
Please provide the output

Comment: i have updated it, it will provide the list of elements, for each element once access to its offsetHeight, the value is correct, but when printing the height it is not the same value

Comment: Perhaps change your for statement to:
`for(var i=0; i < columns.length ; i++) console.log($(".panel-default")[i].clientHeight);`

Comment: same thing , when inspecting element for example the clientHeight's value is 135px, but when logging it, it shows 109px

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: When you inspect the element, the height could change when the viewport changes (if you dock the console at the bottom, it could push the elements up the page) that's the only reason I could see that could cause the heights to change.
It worked for me, so I'm confused as to why it doesn't work for you

Comment: i added it into a $timeout service , it works fine. Maybe widget still not loaded once i want to access to its height